# Correct way to require an array of modules in order using Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

I'm using dojo to modularize my application.

There's a JSON config file that specifies which modules are to be loaded, in an array

I'm not sure how to apply this to Dojo's require library, as it is asynchronous and the syntax is a little odd.

Is there a way to do it in batch? Or do I have to call a new declare for each file.

An is there a way to force an order on the loaded modules? I really need the order to be respected, or at least recovered and ordered later

This is an example of what I've started with, but does not looks right to me (Yes, I'm using the AMD version) :

Maybe there's a way to force it to load synchronously? But I guess that wouldn't be recommended

```
files = ["fileone","filetwo","filethree"] //this would be loaded from a config file

files.forEach((item,i) => {
    dojo.require(item, function(module){
        console.log(module)
    }
})
```

Comment: I think its good begind for what you did , just think to make a config file that contains all references , and then use controller file to require to  load them and ,( try all of this using AMD modern dojo not legacy code )

Comment: @bRIMOs Sorry but I did not understand what you said :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (outer `require` can be replaced with `define` in your module):

```js
require([
"require"
/*, "dojo/text!path/to/config.json" */ 
], function(require /*,config*/){
 var files = ["dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/declare"]; //replace this with array from config 
                                         //(propably needs JSON.parse(config))
  
  require(files, function(){
   console.log("All in one require");
   console.log(arguments);
  });
  
  files.forEach(function(file, i){
   require([file], function(module){
     console.log("ForEach: module nr " + i);
      console.log(module);
    });
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```